# Load component, that is defined from a list?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to load a component that is defined from a array list?
I am loading these views let's as tabs view. I am using angular 2.

I thought first maybe I could list the selectors in the array, 
and than in the view just say <{{menu. componentTop}}> , but that didn't work. Anyone?

**I've constructed a list:**

```
const menus = [
    {id: 1, 
       title: 'A',
       componentTop : 'exampletopBComponent',
       componentbottom: 'examplebottomBComponent';
   },
    {id: 2,  
        title: 'B',
        componentTop : 'exampletopBComponent',
        componentbottom: 'examplebottomBComponent';
    },
    {id: 3,  
        title: 'C', 
         componentTop : 'exampletopCComponent',
         componentbottom: 'examplebottomCComponent';
    {id: 4,  
         title: 'D',
         componentTop : 'userComponent',
         componentbottom: 'profileComponent';
    }];
```

**I've a view with *ngFor loop**

```
   <li *ngFor="let menu of Menus">   
              <div>{{menu.title}}</div>  
              <div class="btn-view">
               I would like to load menu componentTop
              </div>
  </li>
  <div>
   i would like to load menu componentbottom
  </div>
```

Comment: <{{menu. componentTop}}> is really not going to work. Angular does a lot of stuff when it compiles and creates components. I'd take a look at how dialog implementations create components. This is a good example that creates an inserts components into certain places: http://blog.brecht.io/Modals-in-angular2/

Comment: been through many example, but kind searching if any one has a actually working example.

Comment: A working example of creating an inserting an angular component dynamically? Or an example that does exactly what you need using an array? Because you're not going to find the latter, the former, there's a perfectly fine working example in the above comment, I've used it. How about you try do what you want using it and post any problems that cause it not to work?